# Adding Button to change products display form, from row to column like e commerce site React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sorting, product, react-native-flatlist

i try to add 2 button who sort my product from row to column and column to row, i can add more code, but last time someone who try to answer say to not add alot of coding, so if anyone can help me with this short part i will apreciate that, thanks.
[https://fonts.google.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7W4n.png) here is how button look like when u try to sort google fonts

```
                `<View style={styles.productsContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Most popular products</Text>
                    <FlatList 
                        data={this.state.products.specialcars}
                        renderItem = {({item}) => (
                            <View>
                                <Item item={item} />
                            </View>
                        )}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} >
                        <Text style={styles.btnText}>View More</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>`
```

[here is how looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGZQL.png)

[and this is vertical sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auY0k.png)

Comment: You should implement two views one  normal listview and one grid like react-native-super-grid (https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid)

Hit the button will utilize the depending view